# Why did I get offensive flags?

Tags: support, flags

Why did I get these offensive [flags](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/284234)  ? I did not offend anyone since I joined this website. I am astonished !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misreading it. Those are posts that *you* have flagged. Some of them are spam/threats (The Indian Hacker Team), and there are a few others in the same vein.